Vanishing result on cohomology with support
Let $X$ be a locally contractible topological space of dimension at least $2$ and $x \in X$ a point. Is it true that $H^i_x(X)=0$ for all $i>1$? If necessary, assume $X$ is a projective variety and $x$ is the singular point of $X$. Of course, if $X$ is non-singular, then using  the Thom isomorphism the vanishing result is true.

What type of cohomology with support are you using here? Singular cohomology, sheaf cohomology, coherent sheaf cohomology?

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn I am using singular cohomology.
